# report lab libraries not working when python 3.5 script is run from OSX Automator

Tags: python-3.x

I have many python 3.5 scripts to handle my business affairs.  All of these run perfect from IDLE and from the bash shell.  When I create OSX Automator apps they all run well except the included reportlab functions do not work.  I have also attempted to create the app with py2app but this fails to find the qt4 and reportlab libraries and fails.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the errors you get.

Comment: I have included the output from an attempt using py2app.  There is no error message when running the Automator script - it just has no PDF output.                Modules not found (unconditional imports):

Modules not found (conditional imports):
 * HTMLParser (reportlab.platypus.paraparser)
 * Image (reportlab.lib.utils)
 * future_builtins (reportlab)
 * htmlentitydefs (reportlab.platypus.paraparser)
 * jarray (reportlab.lib.utils)
 * javax (reportlab.lib.utils)
 * javax.imageio (reportlab.lib.utils)
 * macfs (reportlab.lib.utils)
 * macostools (reportlab.lib.utils)